# hiding private functions in module using mixin

Tags: elixir, mixins

let's say I have a mixin with a long function, like this:

```
defmodule Mixin do
    @callback cb ...
    defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
        def long_function do
            #a lot of code
            cb(a, b, c)
            #even more code
        end
    end
    end
end
```

so, for readability related stuff I split it into smaller functions:

```
defmodule Mixin do
    @callback cb ...
    defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
        def long_function do
            subfunction_1()
            subfunction_2()
        end
        defp subfunction_1 do
            #some code
            cb(a, b, c)
        end
        defp subfunction_2 do
            #some code
            cb(a, b, c)
            #some code
        end
    end
    end
end
```

and then I use this mixin

```
defmodule MyModule do
    use Mixin

    @Impl Mixin
    def cb(a, b, c) do
        # ...
    end

    def some_other_fun do
        # ...
    end
end
```

the problem is, now in `MyModule` I have access to `subfunction_1` and `subfunction_2` (e.g. from `some_other_fun`), which is unwanted. Moreover, if someone accidentally implemented e.g. `subfunction_1` in `MyModule`, hidden bugs would arise. As subfunctions call callbacks, they either cannot be moved out of using, or module name needs to be passed to them, which is an ugly solution.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

First let's clarify the notation: you are using a module to provide default callback implementations. Talking about mixins is a bit weird because you are not mixing the module contents but rather generating something new.

In general it is a bad practice to generate a lot of contents inside user modules, exactly because of all of the concerns you raised. Instead, you should invoke a function passing all of the relevant arguments, something like this:

```
defmodule Mixin do
  @callback long_function(...) :: ...

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      def long_function(arg1, arg2) do
        Mixin.long_functtion(arg1, arg2)
      end
    end
  end

  def long_function(arg1, arg) do
    ... actual implementation ...
  end
end
```

The `long_function` does not need to be defined in the `Mixin` module, it could be anywhere. The idea is just to keep the generated code short. It should help with unit testing too, as you test `long_function` directly without having to generate tons of modules.

We cover this topic [in the Macro guides too](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html#write-macros-responsibly). I can also recommend Chris McCord's Metaprogramming book.

Comment: Thanks for answer, the problem is that in my case the mixin, or whatever it is, is supplying the abstraction for callbacks, so they are executed quite often in long_function. This also implies that long_function makes sense only along with implementation of lacking callbacks, and there is no point in testing it alone.

Comment: I would say the answer is still the same. Move the logic out of the generated code, either to a public module or a private module that only contains the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the existing answer: refactor the problem code you've given to this:

```
defmodule Mixin do
  @callback cb ...
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      def long_function(args) do
        # you must use the module.fun syntax here, as this code
        # will be injected into the host
        # Also, pass __MODULE__ so that the Mixin functions can find the callback
        Mixin.long_function(__MODULE__, args)
      end
    end
  end

  # host_module is where `use Mixin` appears, and where `cb` is implemented
  def long_function(host_module, args) do
    subfunction_1(host_module, args)
    subfunction_2(host_module, args)
  end

  defp subfunction_1(host_module, args) do
    #some code
    cb(host_module, a, b, c)
  end

  defp subfunction_2(host_module, args) do
    #some code
    cb(host_module, a, b, c)
    #some code
  end

  defp cb(hostmodule, a, b, c) do
    # This is a potential source of runtime errors, you must 
    # manually check that it is being called correctly:
    hostmodule.cb(a, b, c)
  end
end

def MyModule do
  use Mixin
  # expands to: 
  # def long_function(args)

  @impl Mixin
  def cb(a, b, c), do: :something
end
```

Now you have the benefits that José Valim mentions: the interesting code is in pure functions that can be easily tested, and the macro code is extra small. Creating a very simple, very predictable version of the CB module will allow testing your mixing functions/subfunctions trivially. You also gain the syntax you want: being able to call `MyModule.long_function(args)` without leaking subfunctions all over the place.

If a non-toy example is useful, check out how the `create` method and `create_changeset` callback interact in my library [`BaseModel`](https://github.com/meyercm/base_model), which uses this exact pattern.

Comment: This is what I mention in the last sentence, calling it 'ugly solution' :P nevertheless I will probably end up with it. Language mechanism improving this would be useful.

Comment: Which part strikes you as ugly?

Comment: Passing around the module name of course. Maybe it look is a matter of taste, but I think that things like extending modules/providing default callbacks should be compile-time operations. E.g. if you mistake the function name or arity while calling `module.function(...)`, compiler won't warn you.

Comment: Are you hoping to catch that sort of error in the host module or in the Mixin?  If you are using @impl, that should warn you about arity mismatches when defining `cb` in the host; in the Mixin, you could add a function to the Mixin so you are only using the `module.function()` syntax in one place per callback.... Not a perfect solution, but now you only have one source of runtime errors, the rest will be compile-time checked.

Comment: Only one and one too much ;) I know that those runtime errors are not likely to happen and can be quite easily debugged, that's why I think It's not a bad solution (and upvoted), it just doesn't look well